# String Cases Pattern Questions

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Say I have the function:

```
dep = TextStructure["He wrote a book. I read the book he wrote.", 
  "DependencyStrings", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

Which outputs:

```
{"(wrote, 2)((nsubj, (He, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (a, 3)))))", \
"(read, 2)((nsubj, (I, 1)), (dobj, (book, 4)((det, (the, 3)), (rcmod, \
(wrote, 6)((nsubj, (he, 5)))))))"}
```

Firstly, I want to extract each case of nsubj with the list:

```
{{"He"},{"I","he"}}
```

I have tried below but to no avail.

```
StringCases[dep, 
 Shortest["subj," ~~ __ ~~ 
    x : (LetterCharacter ~~ __ ~~ WordBoundary) /; x]]
```

This gets me half way, but it's not good enough:

```
StringCases[dep, Shortest["subj," ~~ __ ~~ ")"]]
```

Secondly, I want to get the root of the dependency which is the first word number pair of each sentence.

```
{{"wrote"},{"read"}}
```

If it were an expression it would be easy through:

```
Cases[dep, {s_Symbol, _Integer} :> ToString@s, 1]]
```

But I need to extract it from a string.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

```
StringCases[dep, 
 "((nsubj, (" ~~ w : WordCharacter .. ~~ ", " ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ "))" :> w]

StringCases[dep, "(" ~~ w : WordCharacter .. ~~ ___ :> w]
```

> ```
> {{"He"}, {"I", "he"}}
>
> {{"wrote"}, {"read"}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

A Regex attempt:

```
StringCases[#, 
  RegularExpression["[(]nsubj,\s+[(]([^,]+)"] :> "$1"]&/@dep
```

> {{He}, {I, he}}

```
StringCases[#, 
  RegularExpression["^[(]([^,]+)"] :> "$1"]&/@dep
```

> {{wrote}, {read}}